# Is there a way that I can tell my program that it has an "empty hand "?

Tags: java, for-loop, methods

Basically it's a card point counter and it counts points based on your cards. However, Ih have to also acknowledge the fact that someone might not even have cards. So my question is how I can tell my program it has an empty hand?

I was thinking about incorporating this method

hand.isEmpty();

but is it even possible to put a method inside a method?

Here's my code

```
public int countDeadwood(String hand) {

   int deadwood = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < hand.length() ; i = i + 1)
   {

       if (hand.charAt(i)=='A')
           deadwood = deadwood + 1;
       if (hand.charAt(i)=='K')
           deadwood = deadwood + 10;
       if (hand.charAt(i)=='Q')
           deadwood = deadwood + 10;    
       if (hand.charAt(i)=='J')
           deadwood = deadwood + 10;
       if (hand.charAt(i)== 'T')
           deadwood = deadwood + 10;   
       if (hand.charAt(i)== 9)
           deadwood = deadwood + 9;
       if (hand.charAt(i)== 8)
           deadwood = deadwood + 8;
       if (hand.charAt(i)== 7)
           deadwood = deadwood + 7;
       if (hand.charAt(i)== 6)
           deadwood = deadwood + 6;
       if (hand.charAt(i)== 5)
           deadwood = deadwood + 5;
       if (hand.charAt(i)== 4)
           deadwood = deadwood + 4;
       if (hand.charAt(i)== 3)
           deadwood = deadwood + 3; 
       if (hand.charAt(i)== 2)
           deadwood = deadwood + 2;


   }
   return deadwood;
}
```

Or is there another way to add in empty hand?

Comment: It's certainly possible to *call* a method inside a method. You're already doing so with `hand.length()` and `hand.charAt()`.

Answer (score 0):

To start of, I would like to point out the logic you are using to calculate the deadwood value isn't very elegant; At the very least you should use an if-else, though the following may be a much better approach. Ofcourse, this assumes every character represents a card and only valid cards can and will be encountered.

```
   char c = hand.charAt(i);
   if (c == 'A') {
       value += 1;
   } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) { 
       value += c - '0';
   } else {
       value += 10;
   }
```

To check acknowledge if someone doesn't have any cards, you can check if there are any cards.

```
   int deadwood = 0;
   if (hand.isEmpty()) {
       System.out.println("You have no cards");
   } else {
       for (int i = 0; i < hand.length(); i++) {
           char c = hand.charAt(i);
           if (c == 'A') {
               deadwood += 1;
           } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
               deadwood += c - '0';
           } else {
               deadwood += 10;
           }
       }
       System.out.println("You have " + deadwood + " points");
   }
   return deadwood;
```

Though, if you only need to acknowledge someone has no cards by returning 0, you don't actually need to do anything.

```
  int deadwood = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < hand.length(); i++) {
      char c = hand.charAt(i);
      if (c == 'A') {
          deadwood += 1;
      } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
          deadwood += c - '0';
      } else {
          deadwood += 10;
      }
  }
  return deadwood;
```

Comment: Ohh this might come in handy. Thing is, I'm not suppose to use we haven't covered yet. Array is that we haven;t touched yet.

Comment: Using `charAt(int i)` and the for loop you had is perfectly fine. Using `hand.isEmpty()` does the same thing as checking whether the length of the array is empty regardless.

Answer (score -1):

Just do an if check in that method that uses the isEmpty() method.

Example:

```
if(hand.isEmpty())
{
    //System.out.println("Sorry you have no cards");
    break; //break out of the entire for loop
}
```

Comment: i took your advice and the code that I did was

" deadwood = 0: "

and well I was wondering how i can stop the loop  if i have an empty hand ? Because if i have an empty hand well you get no points.

Comment: Ah, well in that case you can do within the if check that says hand.isEmpty(), just write break with a semicolon at the end. I changed my answer to show you how. This says that if this if statement happens then i want to break out of the for loop and stop all looping/iteration from happening now. so do your deadman = 0 and then also do break on a new line and that is it.

Comment: No worries, if this accomplished your issue, could you mark it as accepted. Much appreciated. :)

Comment: What was the reason for the downvote so I can improve for next time?

Comment: That wasn't me. You gave me critical advice and for that, thank you!